# how to get last 4 digits of credit card after successful paypal payment

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal express checkout api. I need to get last 4 digits of credit card after transaction complete. 
I have tried to find after

> $getExpressCheckoutDetailsRequest = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType(JFactory::getApplication()->input->getString('token'));

and

> $DoECResponse = $paypalService->DoExpressCheckoutPayment($DoECReq);

But I still can not find where is it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the express checkout API you won't get that information. The idea behind PayPal is that buyers don't need to share their card details with sellers.
Here you can find all values that you get back using the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call:

[documentation - GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)

here is all possible calls:
[Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#ec)

Comment: So is there any way to get it with other api?

Comment: You can try using PayPal PayFlow Gateway: "Payflow Gateway is PayPal's secure and open payment gateway. Using the Payflow Gateway APIs, merchants can process debit and credit card payments, PayPal, PayPal Credit®, authorizations, captures, and credit voids"
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/